# .htaccess parameters redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with a `.htaccess` file. I have a url like `http://example.com/auction/category.php?lvl_1=texnologia`. I use the code in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /auction/category.php?lvl_1=$1 [L]
```

And it works perfectly: `http://example.com/texnologia`

- But, would also like to use `http://example.com/auction/category.php?lvl_1=texnologia&lvl_2=gaming` to go to `http://example.com/texnologia/gaming`.
- And `http://example.com/auction/category.php?lvl_1=texnologia&lvl_2=gaming&lvl_3=konsoles` to go to
  `http://example.com/texnologia/gaming/konsoles`.

Under my earlier code, I put:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /auction/category.php?lvl_1=$1&lvl_2=$2 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /auction/category.php?lvl_1=$1&lvl_2=$2&lvl_3=$3 [L]
```

But, I get a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

(you need to make sure that `/auction/category.php` is not matched with any rule, otherwise you will end up with redirect loop)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /auction/category.php?lvl_1=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/auction/category\.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /auction/category.php?lvl_1=$1&lvl_2=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /auction/category.php?lvl_1=$1&lvl_2=$2&lvl_3=$3 [L]
```